While fetching from ESQL, inner struct fields are not getting populated
I am using the new ESQL library in Go. While fetching data from it, the fields of inner structs are not getting populated.
type ProcessedLog struct {
    EventName    string                 `json:"event_name"`
    SessionId    string                 `json:"session_id"`
    Device       Device                 `json:"device"`
    User         User                   `json:"user"`
}

func (e ElasticStore) Logs(sessionId string, date string) ([]ProcessedLog, error) {
    query := "FROM " + e.rawLogIndex + "_" + date +
        ` | WHERE session_id == "` + sessionId + `"`
    return EsqlQueryMapper[ProcessedLog](query)
}

func EsqlQueryMapper[T any](queryStr string) ([]T, error) {
    qry := instance.client.Esql.Query().Query(queryStr)
    return query.Helper[T](context.Background(), qry)
}

Here, the EventName and SessionId gets populated but the fields in the Device and User struct do not.
